# Testing a app script

Tags: unit-testing, testing, google-apps-script, google-docs

I have created a script via Drive|New|App Script

Now I want to test it. This must be so fundamental that it must be obvious, but it is not to me.

My script is for a Document. I used the code example from this "Translate" example, https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/docs

I have tried creating a new document and then from the menu Tools|Script-editor I have gone looking for my saved project, but the "Open recent projects" is empty.

How do you test/run a saved app script project for a Apps Document?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What you created is a standalone script but what you are trying to do is create a bounded script(scripts to be attached to google products). You cannot import standalone scripts into bounded scripts. Bottom of the page at this link https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone you'll see the type of scripts. I would suggest you copy code from your standalone script to your bounded script.

Answer (score 1):

If created Via Google Drive you can type the following in the search whilst in Drive (Drive.google.com)

> Type:Script

This should return all the scripts created manually which are not attached to specific Sheets/Docs/Forms (i.e you have used the Drive tool to create a script or used the URL Script.google.com)

If you have created it this way and want to run a function to interact with a Google Sheet/Doc see the following example.

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
```

CHANGE TO;

```
SpreadsheetApp.openById('SHEETS ID GOES INBETWEEN THESE BRACKETS').getSheetByName('Sheet1')
```

> https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/UNIQUE-ID-IS-HERE

OR YOU COULD CREATE A NEW APPSCRIPT USING THE TOOLS>SCRIPT EDITOR

All tests on appscript are run using the '>' play icon or 'RUN' then select your function.

Answer (score 0):

Don't create your script in "Drive|New|App Script". Open a new Google Doc, open "Tools|Script editor..." and write your code in this new app script project.

Normally this must work!

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

Follow the referred tutorial instructions.

## Explanation

The path that you followed to create the script project, creates a stand-alone script project, but the referred tutorial is about a Google Document bounded-script. The code include triggers and methods that only work on this kind of script project.